# NoSuchMethodError with Hamcrest 1.3 and Maven on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, dependencies, hamcrest

I've already found three questions which should relate to the same problem, but somehow they didn't quite solve my problem.

[NoSuchMethodError with Hamcrest 1.3 & JUnit 4.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833015/nosuchmethoderror-with-hamcrest-1-3-junit-4-11)

[NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasXPath when I run tests in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188337/nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matchers-hasxpath-when-i-run-tests-in-eclipse)

[Getting "NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch" when running test in IntelliJ 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869711/getting-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch-when-running)

The Unit tests work out fine but it is during the Integration Tests when the RestAssured Tests fail:

```
expect().
    statusCode(Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).log().all().
when().
    post("/projects").
then().
    body("directory", Matchers.anything()).body("files", Matchers.empty());
```

As the other three related questions already said, there seem to be some issues with conflicting dependencies of TestNG/JUnit and Hamcrest and/or Mockito, so I tried various exlusions and other inclusions of said artifacts, unfortunately to no avail. What worked though was to not use the log().all() in RestAssured, which must be the origin of the problem. Therefore this would work:

```
expect().
    statusCode(Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).
when().
    post("/projects").
then().
    body("directory", Matchers.anything()).body("files", Matchers.empty());
```

I'd like to be able to see the actual output of the REST calls while esting though, so I'm glad for any thoughts on this. Thanks!

Here's the **console output**

```
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf.any(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;
        at org.hamcrest.Matchers.any(Matchers.java:371)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter.<init>(ResponseLoggingFilter.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:198)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.logWith(ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.groovy:85)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.this$3$logWith(ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl$this$3$logWith.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.all(ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.groovy:45)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.all(ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at com.jayway.restassured.specification.LogSpecification$all.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.all(ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.groovy:41)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.all(ResponseLogSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at de.uniluebeck.collaboratex.test.service.ProjectServiceTests.testDeleteNonExistingProject(ProjectServiceTests.java:84)
```

And the **pom.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>de.uniluebeck.collaboratex</groupId>
    <artifactId>CollaboraTex</artifactId>

    <name>CollaboraTex</name>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>google-staging</id>
            <name>Google Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgoogleappengine-1004/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <appengine.target.version>1.9.2</appengine.target.version>
        <datanucleus.version>3.1.3</datanucleus.version>
        <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey WS-RS dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Data Nucleus dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- needed to solve JPA Data Nucleus validation error -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>2.6</version>  
                <configuration>  
                    <includes>  
                        <include>**/*ServiceTests.java</include>  
                    </includes>  
                </configuration>  
                <executions>
                    <execution>  
                        <id>it</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>  
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>  
                        </goals>  
                    </execution>  
                </executions>  
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <!-- 
                <configuration>
                    <port>7378</port>
                    <offline>true</offline>
                </configuration>
                -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-gae</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>devserver_start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-gae</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>devserver_stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>             
                    <mappingIncludes>**/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                    <fork>false</fork>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And last but not least, here is the output of **mvn dependency:tree**

```
de.uniluebeck.collaboratex:CollaboraTex:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.2:compile
+- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
+- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
+- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.6:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.6:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.6:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.6:compile
|  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
|  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
+- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.6:compile
|  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:compile
+- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.6:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.6:compile
|  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.5.0:compile
+- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
+- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.5.0:compile
|  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.5.0:compile
+- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.5.0:compile
+- com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:jar:2.1.2:compile
|  \- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:jar:3.1.1:compile
|     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:compile
+- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:3.1.3:runtime
+- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:jar:3.1.3:compile
+- javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
|  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
+- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:jar:2.3.1:test
|  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.2.1:test
|  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:4.1:test
|  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:test
|  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:4.1:test
|  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.1:test
|  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:4.1:test
|  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.2.1:test
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.6:test
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.5:test
|  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
|  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:test
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.6:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
|  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
|  \- com.jayway.restassured:xml-path:jar:2.3.1:test
+- com.jayway.restassured:json-path:jar:2.3.1:test
|  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.2.1:test
|  \- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured-common:jar:2.3.1:test
+- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
+- org.testng:testng:jar:6.8.7:test
|  +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
|  +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
|  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
|  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.12:test
+- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
+- com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.9.2:test
+- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.9.2:test
\- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.9.2:test
```

Comment: Is this while running junit tests or in production?

Comment: Sorry, while running the integration tests for REST Services, Unit tests work out fine. I added it to my description as well as the corssorponding REST call, thank you pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, the `<scope>test</scope>` makes library only available in unit tests.

Comment: In other words every dependency marked with <scope>test</scope> will work in unit but not in the integration tests?

Comment: If you run integration tests as normal production, then yes they will not see test libs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TestNG has a dependency on JUnit. Therefore junit-4.10.jar is in your class path. This Jar includes Hamcrest classes that are older than Hamcrest 1.3 and are missing some methods. The classloader loads `org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf` from JUnit and therefore you're running into problems.

Add a dependency to JUnit 4.11 to your POM. This overrides TestNG's dependency to JUnit 4.10 and solves your Hamcrest problems, because JUnit 4.11 no longer includes Hamcrest classes.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I cannot believe how simple it was to solve in the end. I've actually tried that one already but back then on an older version of testng (figured 6.8.2 wasn't quite the newest kid on the block and still had an old junit with hamcrest 1.1 dependencies). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's still a jar on a classpath that exposes pre hamcrest 1.3 classes, as the mentioned method was only added in 1.3RC4: https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/commit/a6b00c4aadae733236e481fa747d5223cc7b7a9a

I suggest debugging this in your favorite IDE in order to make sure it's so. After that I suggest checking dependency hierarchy for this maven project and figure out the villain.

If that fails it could be the case the jar/class is there by mistake and only checking this in file system might help I guess.

Comment: I relied heavily on Maven's **dependency:analyze** plugin, removing unnecessary dependencies and adding a few missing ones. I updated the pom in my original post accordingly and added a code example. What I found out so far is that using _log().all()_ in RestAssured is causing this problem